# Replicate large numbers on Calculator display in JS

Tags: javascript, math

Not sure on the right terminology here, sorry!

Is there anyway to replicate a calculator display for large numbers in JS?

**Sum:**

```
999999999*999999999
```

**Calculator:**

```
Result: 9.99999998e17
```

**JS:**

```
Result: 999999998000000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Number.prototype.toExponential` can turn a number into an exponentially-formatted number - pass it the number of desired digits:

```js
console.log(
  (999999999*999999999).toExponential(8)
);
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a million for this!  (Will accept in 10 mins when I can!)